# Why does this byte[] not equal my other byte[] with the same values?

Tags: c#, compare, arrays

```
public static readonly byte[] TestArray=
    new byte[] { 0x75, 0xa5, 0x15, 0x19, 0xa0, 0x2e, 0xd9, 0x37, 0xb0, 0x4d };

public bool TestFunction() 
{
    MemoryStream s=new MemoryStream(
        new byte[] { 0x75, 0xa5, 0x15, 0x19, 0xa0, 0x2e, 0xd9, 0x37, 0xb0, 0x4d }
        );

    byte[] test=s.ToArray();
    return (test==TestArray);
}
```

I am using the above simple code. The byte values in the arrays are equal. But my `TestFunction()` always returns false. What is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because arrays are reference types in .Net, and for arrays, the `==` operator just checks to see if they are a reference to the same object in memory. You need to [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) use this to compare each byte:

```
test.SequenceEqual(TestArray);
```

Comment: Because they are reference type *and* they use the default comparison, which is by reference. There are reference types with overloaded `==` and overridden `Equals` for which this isn't the case.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks, I tried to make that more clear in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not comparing the individual members of each array; you are comparing the *references* to each array, which are not equal.

Use [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator, in this case, checks if the references are equal, not if the content of the byte arrays are equal. You should iterate the byte arrays and check if they're equal byte by byte or use a method that does that.

I suppose you took this out of your code somewhere, but the `MemoryStream` usage is a bit pointless, you can just do the following:

```
byte[] test = new byte[] { 0x75, 0xa5, 0x15, 0x19, 0xa0, 0x2e, 0xd9, 0x37, 0xb0, 0x4d };
```

Comment: Added "in this case" to make the distinction.

Comment: This is part of a much larger application where I am manipulating `MemoryStream`s. I thought it may be relevant as a cause of the problem so I included it.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing *references* to objects, i.e. the `==` operator - in case of byte arrays - returns true if and only if the two references are pointing to the same object. But in fact you have two different objects, which have equal contents though.

You have to use the `SequenceEqual` method to compare the *contents* of two arrays.

Note that the `==` operator can be overloaded for some classes, so that it compares contents of objects (or even has some other logic). However, for byte arrays, the `==` is not overloaded, so the default is to just compare references.

Answer (score 0):

The equals comparator will not do what is called a 'deep equals' check. In other words, the equals operator only checks if two arrays/objects are stored in the same place in memory (in other words, if the object reference is the same).

To check if the values of two arrays are equal, you need to write a function that checks each value individually.

Comment: The `==` operator does whatever the type defined it to do.  The default behavior, if not overloaded, for reference types is to compare references, and for value types to do a bitwise comparison of all fields, but that's just the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Because byte[] is a reference type and while you are comparing two byte array you, actually compare their references to their locations in memory not their values

Answer (score 0):

When, in your example, you use the equality operator (`==`), you are comparing the array references as everybody said, not it's values.

A simple test:

```
byte[] originalArray = new byte[] { 0x75, 0xa5, 0x15, 0x19, 0xa0, 0x2e, 0xd9, 0x37, 0xb0, 0x4d };

byte[] sameReferenceArray = originalArray;
originalArray == sameReferenceArray; //true

byte[] sameContentArray = new byte[] { 0x75, 0xa5, 0x15, 0x19, 0xa0, 0x2e, 0xd9, 0x37, 0xb0, 0x4d };
originalArray == sameContentArray; //false
```

Comment: The `==` operator does whatever the type defined it to do.  The default behavior, if not overloaded, for reference types is to compare references, and for value types to do a bitwise comparison of all fields, but that's just the default behavior.

Comment: @Servy Indeed. And since arrays are reference types comparing it using the `==` operator will compare it references, as he does in his code. Edited the question to clarify that I was referencing to his example.

Comment: As I said, just because it's a reference types doesn't mean that `==` will compare references.  That's just the default behavior if it's not overridden, which any type can do.  The array type simply doesn't override it.

Comment: @Servy As I said, indeed. Nobody is denying it :)

Answer (score 0):

The code of `MemoryStream.ToArray` is:

```
public virtual byte[] ToArray() {
    byte[] dst=new byte[this._length-this._origin];
    Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(this._buffer, this._origin, dst, 0, this._length-this._origin);
    return dst;
}
```

And the real reason you get false is, you declared two arrays, but compared on another things. This kind of comparision will not be true even in C.